# Help with Homework Problem for Img Processing class

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing

I have this homework about Image Processing:

1. Give the general equation of a complex or real-valued digital image that produces a
   delta function in the frequency domain.
2. Demonstrate this function for an image of size 8×8. Make sure to center the fft magnitude display using log(1+abs(fftshift(fft2(img)))).
3. Also, to establish that the complex part is zero, you can use max(abs(imag(fftimg(:)))).

I'm very lost and it is due tomorrow.

*Does anyone have ideas about how to solve this problems?*

I kinda understand part 1. He wanst me to find a function that, once Fourier transformed, we get a Delta function (like the Dirac Delta Function). But I have no idea about how to get such a function.

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that the image is given by $M[8][8]$. I believe that the function they want is $\Delta[i][0]=M[i][0]$ and $\Delta[i][j]=M[i][j]-M[i][j-1]$.

Comment: Why do you think so @barakmanos ? How did you get to that conclussion?

Answer (score 1):

A constant function! That's a function that after FFT results in a delta function.

The part b is used to center the transform (just like multiplying the function by (-1)x+y).